# Inserting values into table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JIMMY-PC;initial Catalog=jimmy;
                                   Integrated Security=true");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee ('First Name','Middle Name',
                     'Last Name','D O B','Sex','Address')values (@FName,@MName,@LName,
                      @DOB,@Sex,@Address)", con);
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname",TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname",TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname",TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB",TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", RadioButton1.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address",TextBox5.Text);
        con.Open();
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Registered successfully......!')</script>");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

i'm new to the asp.net please help me out.
i tried using cmd.executenonquery but there is some error...  and is there any problem with my connection string?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: `"@Fname",SqlDbType.Varchar,20` here i have used ntext in the DB and now i'm getting **blue underline** in that field
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname",SqlDbType.ntext).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mname",SqlDbType.ntext).Value = TextBox2.Text;`

Comment: ERROR is : **'System.Data.SqlDbType' does not contain a definition for 'ntext'**

Comment: ntext is the datatype which i have selected in the sql management studio

Comment: It should be `NText` and not `ntext` further reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Izzy NText worked thanks but now i'm stuck with other two data types
`cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB",SqlDbType.smalldatetime).Value = TextBox4.Text;` and `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address",SqlDbType.NVarchar,(MAX)).Value = TextBox5.Text;`
please help me

Comment: @izzy ty.. i read your earlier comment now.. cleared all data types error!! hope it will run now :P thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to pass selectedItem Text/Value in-place of ListItem. If below code is not work for you than please provide error detail and also mention that where you called this execute method.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", RadioButton1.SelectedItem.Text)
//OR
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", RadioButton1.SelectedItem.Value)
```

Comment: Hey! thanks.. there no error now! but nothing is updating in the back end server. There is any executable codes which i should add after those parameters.addwithvalue??

Comment: Not sure but because of connection string issue you are not able to add data into database.

Answer (score 0):

It would better to change your SqlCommand like this：

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee ([First Name],[Middle Name],[Last Name],[D O B],[Sex],[Address])
values (@FName,@MName,@LName,@DOB,@Sex,@Address)", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 con.Open();
            string Title = ddl_title.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string FirstName = txtname.Text;
            string MiddleName = txtmiddlename.Text;
            string LastName = txtlastname.Text;
            string Gender = ddl_gender.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string DateOfBirth = txtdateofbirth.Text;
            string Age = txtage.Text;
            string Cast = txtcast.Text;
            string Address = txtaddress.Text;
            string City = txtcity.Text;
            string Area = txtarea.Text;
            string PinCode = txtpincode.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into AddNewMemberWomenExecutiveCommittee Values('"+Title+"','"+FirstName+"','"+MiddleName+"','"+LastName+"','"+Gender+"','"+DateOfBirth+"','"+Age+"','"+Cast+"','"+Address+"','"+City+"','"+Area+"','"+PinCode+"')", con);


            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (i == 1)

                Response.Write("Insert Successfully");
            con.Close();
            GetData();
```

`(1)con.open();//----->open the connection 
(2)SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Query,con");//--->command object
(3)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();----->function for insert, update, delete (4)con.close();-------->close the connnection, where con is connection object`

Comment: it would be a good idea to explain your code a little rather than just dumping it on here

Comment: con.open()//----->open the connection (2)SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Query,con");//--->command object(3)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();----->function for insert, update, delete,

Comment: con.open();//----->open the connection (2)SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Query,con");//--->command object(3)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();----->function for insert, update, delete (4)con.close();-------->close the connnection,  where con is connection object

Comment: Don't write it as a comment explain it in your answer